# show certain elements in an array

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a 6 divs (although the code should work for any number of divs). I want to show 4 `divs` at a time when the button `#more-projects` is clicked. Ideally, the the first 4 divs would be shown when the `#more-projects` is clicked for the first time, when it's clicked again all divs are hidden and then the next `divs` are shown in this case it would be 5 and 6 would be along with 1 and 2. Whenever the `#more-projects` is clicked the next four `divs` would be shown. Below is my approach but I don't know how to progress

```js
$('#more-projects').on('click', function() {
    var projects = [];
    var shown = [];
    var start = [];

    $('.thumbnail-cnt').each(function(i) {
        projects.push($(this).data('num'));
    })
    var shown = projects.slice(0,4);
    $('[data-num="' + shown.join('"], [data-id="') + '"]').addClass('visible');

});
```

```css
.thumbnail-cnt {
    display: none;
}
.visible {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-ZosEbRLbNQzLpnKIkEdrPv7lOy9C27hHQ+Xp8a4MxAQ="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="thumbnail-cnt" data-num="1">
</div>
<div class="thumbnail-cnt" data-num="2">
</div>
<div class="thumbnail-cnt" data-num="3">
</div>
<div class="thumbnail-cnt" data-num="4">
</div>
<div class="thumbnail-cnt" data-num="5">
</div>
<div class="thumbnail-cnt" data-num="6">
</div>

<button id="more-projects">
</button>
```

From here I was going slice the projects to be shown, add class `.visible` and make a var of the index in the array that should be the starting point of the next 4 projects. But I don't know how to implement this of to cycle back to the start of the array. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: should `$('[data-num="' + shown.join('"], [data-id="') + '"]')` not be `$('[data-num="' + shown.join('"], [data-num="') + '"]')`

Comment: Looks like you just need a `var offset = 0;` above all that JS. And on click: `projects.slice(0 + offset, 4 + offset); offset += 4;`

Comment: Thank you very much for replying. The main thing i'm struggling with is essentially making the array an eternal circle and storing the starting index each time. When the code is executed divs 1, 2, 3, 4 would be shown the starting number would be 5, when it's executed again divs 5, 6, 1, 2 are shown, here the starting number is 3,  executed again, 3, 4, 5, 6, the starting number is 1.

Answer (score 1):

Please check this code

**HTML**

```
<div id="container">
<div class="thumbnail-cnt" data-num="1">1
</div>
<div class="thumbnail-cnt" data-num="2">2
</div>
<div class="thumbnail-cnt" data-num="3">3
</div>
<div class="thumbnail-cnt" data-num="4">4
</div>
<div class="thumbnail-cnt" data-num="5">5
</div>
<div class="thumbnail-cnt" data-num="6">6
</div>
</div>
<button id="more-projects" > Next
</button>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   var divQueue = [];

   $("#container div").each(function(){
        divQueue.push($(this));
   });

   function showDivs(){
     $("#container").html('');
     $(".thumbnail-cnt").css("display","none");
     var i=0;
     while(i<4){
        var temp = divQueue[0];
        $("#container").append(temp[0]);
        divQueue.shift();
        divQueue.push(temp);
        i++; 
     }
   }

   showDivs();

   $("#more-projects").click(function(){
   showDivs();
   });
});
```

**CSS**

```
.thumbnail-cnt {
    height : 30px;
    width : 25px;
}

#more-projects {
  width : 100px;
  height : 50px;
}
```

Please refer [`Fiddle`](https://jsfiddle.net/r6wwL1ne/22/)

Answer (score 0):

I would try to assign an id for each div, something like:

```
<div class="thumbnail-cnt" id="div1" data-num="1">
</div>
<div class="thumbnail-cnt" id="div2" data-num="2">
</div>
<div class="thumbnail-cnt" id="div3" data-num="3">
</div>
<div class="thumbnail-cnt" id="div4" data-num="4">
</div>
<div class="thumbnail-cnt" id="div5" data-num="5">
</div>
```

If you are using Jquery you can use the methods `hide()` and `show()`

If you want to show X divs:

```
for(var i = 1; i < X; i ++){
  $('#div'+i).show();
}    
for(var i = X; i < numDivs; i ++){
  $('#div'+i).hide();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `arrays` have managed to rotate the divs. Check if this is what you are looking for:

```js
var divs = [];
$('.thumbnail-cnt').each(function() {
  divs['' + $(this).index() + ''] = $(this).data('num');
  divs.push($(this).text());
});
divs.splice(0, 1);

$('#more-projects').on('click', function() {
  $('.thumbnail-cnt').hide();
  var count = 0;
  $(divs).each(function(k, v) {
    if (count == 4)
      return false;
    $('.thumbnail-cnt[data-num="' + v + '"]').show();
    divs.push(divs.shift());
    count++;
  });
});
```

```css
.thumbnail-cnt {
  display: none;
}

.visible {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="thumbnail-cnt" data-num=1>Test 1</div>
<div class="thumbnail-cnt" data-num=2>Test 2</div>
<div class="thumbnail-cnt" data-num=3>Test 3</div>
<div class="thumbnail-cnt" data-num=4>Test 4</div>
<div class="thumbnail-cnt" data-num=5>Test 5</div>
<div class="thumbnail-cnt" data-num=6>Test 6</div>
<div class="thumbnail-cnt" data-num=7>Test 7</div>
<div class="thumbnail-cnt" data-num=8>Test 8</div>
<div class="thumbnail-cnt" data-num=9>Test 9</div>
<button id="more-projects">More</button>
```